# Renaming index with a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, indexing

Let's say I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3))

columns = ['Score A','Score B','Score C']
index = ['18','25','30']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=index,columns=columns)

print(df)
```

I wanted the index to show instead 'Age 18', 'Age 25' and 'Age 30'
So I did some manipulation and created the list ['Age 18', 'Age 25', 'Age 30']
Is there a quick way to rename the index based on my new list, without me resorting to using a dictionary, which requires me to map all the old index to new index one by one?

Comment: `df.index = ['Age '+i for i in df.index]`

Comment: In the shown example your index is already a string so you can just do `df.index = 'Age ' + df.index`. Or `df.index = 'Age ' + df.index.astype(str)` if you actually had numbers in the real case. `rename` can also be helpful and works regardless of type `df = df.rename('Age {}'.format)` (Though it can be expensive as it returns a copy of the DataFrame) Or similarly with `index.map` -> `df.index = df.index.map('Age {}'.format)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `add_prefix`

```
 df = df.T.add_prefix('Age ').T
```